# activestate pythonwin missing import modules?

Tags: python, import

I'm working my way through DiveIntoPython.com and I'm having trouble getting the import  to work.  I've installed ActiveState's Pythonwin on a windows xp prof environment.

In the website, there is an exercise which involves 'import odbchelper' and odbchelper.**name**

http://www.diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/testing_modules.html

When I run it interactive, i get:

```
>>> import odbchelper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named odbchelper
>>> odbchelper.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'odbchelper' is not defined
```

I'm guessing either i don't have the pathing set correctly or the module does not exist referenced in one of the folders when I run 'sys.path'.  Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module doesn't come packaged with Python2.6 for sure (just tried on my machine). Have you tried googling where this module might be?

Consider this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=487584).

Comment: yea i found something similar..  you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out..

found this:

```
http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/odbchelper_divein.html
```

downloaded the file and then put it into a folder.  c:\temp\python\ in my case with the commands:

```
>> import sys 
>> sys.path.append('c:\\temp\\python\\')
```

Comment: I thought it was a built-in, but you're right it comes with Dive into Python itself